# display fieldname in output using Filehelpers.dll

Tags: vb.net, filehelpers, field-names

want to display fieldname in the output but i got no idea how to solve this. anybody pls help..

#### Test.aspx.vb

```
Private Sub IFexportData()
    Try
        Dim fileLog, filePath, fileName As String

        fileLog = Year(dtDate.Text) & Month(dtDate.Text) & Day(dtDate.Text) & ".log"
        filePath = configurationAppSettings.GetValue("ExtractPath", GetType(System.String))
        fileName = filePath & "\" & fileLog

        Dim IFStorage As New SqlServerStorage(GetType(IFFormat))

        Dim cipherUsername, cipherPassword As Byte()
        cipherUsername = Encoder.Base64Decode(configurationAppSettings.GetValue("UserID", _
                GetType(System.String)))
        cipherPassword = Encoder.Base64Decode(configurationAppSettings.GetValue("Password", _
                GetType(System.String)))

        With IFStorage
            '.TransactionMode = 3
            .DatabaseName = configurationAppSettings.GetValue("DatabaseName", GetType(System.String))
            .ServerName = configurationAppSettings.GetValue("ServerName", GetType(System.String))
            .UserName = Dpapi.Decrypt(cipherUsername)
            .UserPass = Dpapi.Decrypt(cipherPassword)
        End With

        IFStorage.SelectSql = "SELECT" & vbCrLf & _
                            "m.Key, ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR,m.Date,20),'') AS Date," & vbCrLf & _
                            "ISNULL(m.Loc,'') AS Loc," & vbCrLf & _
                            "ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR,m.Sched,20),'') AS Sched" & vbCrLf & _ 
                            "FROM TAB1 p INNER JOIN" & vbCrLf & _
                            "TAB2 m ON p.Code = m.Code" & vbCrLf & _
                            "ORDER BY m.Date, m.Loc, Sched" & vbCrLf


        IFStorage.FillRecordCallback = New FillRecordHandler(AddressOf FillIFRecord)
        Dim res As IFFormat() = CType(IFStorage.ExtractRecords, IFFormat())

        Dim link As New FileDataLink(IFStorage)
        link.ExtractToFile(fileName)

        Dim file As System.IO.FileInfo = New System.IO.FileInfo(fileName)
        If file.Exists Then  'set appropriate headers  

            Response.Clear()
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" & file.Name)
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", file.Length.ToString())
            Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream"
            Response.WriteFile(file.FullName)
            Response.End() 'if file does not exist  
        Else
            Response.Write("This file does not exist.")
        End If 'nothing in the URL as HTTP GET  
    Catch ex As Exception
        Response.Write("<script language=javascript>alert('" & ex.Message.Replace("'", """") & "');</script>")
    End Try
End Sub

Protected Sub FillIFRecord(ByVal rec As Object, ByVal fields() As Object)
    Dim record As IFFormat
    record = rec

    record.Key = fields(0)
    record.Date = fields(1)
    record.Loc = fields(2)
    record.Sched = fields(3)
End Sub
```

#### IFFormat.vb

```
[DelimitedRecord(",")]
Public Class IFFormat
    Public Key As String
    Public Date As String
    [FieldQuoted()] Public Loc As String
    Public Sched As String
End Class
```

The sample output from `xxxxxxxxxxx.log` I got:

```
1896044529,2012-10-01 00:00:00,"ABC",2012-10-01 04:10:00
1896044529,2012-10-01 00:00:00,"DEF",2012-10-01 04:22:00
1896044663,2012-10-01 00:00:00,"GHI",2012-10-01 04:36:00
1896044672,2012-10-01 00:00:00,"JKL",2012-10-01 04:44:00
```

The output that I want :

```
"Key","Date","Loc","Sched"
1896044529,2012-10-01 00:00:00,"ABC",2012-10-01 04:10:00
1896044529,2012-10-01 00:00:00,"DEF",2012-10-01 04:22:00
1896044663,2012-10-01 00:00:00,"GHI",2012-10-01 04:36:00
1896044672,2012-10-01 00:00:00,"JKL",2012-10-01 04:44:00
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `HeaderText` of the FileHelpersEngine to whatever you want.

```
Dim link As New FileDataLink(IFStorage)
link.FileHelperEngine.HeaderText = """Key"", ""Date"", ""Loc"", ""Sched"""
link.ExtractToFile(fileName)
```